# type parms of np.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

when I type

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float64)
```

pylance tells me a's type is:

```py
(variable) a: ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]
```

I have no idea about these two `Unknown` mean.

Referrer to the stub file

```py
class ndarray(_ArrayOrScalarCommon, Generic[_ShapeType, _DType_co]):
```

I still don't know about it. How can I fill them?

Comment: The `a` expression is perfectly good `numpy`.  I don't know what `pylance` is complaining about.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Unknown` means that the type checker can't solve the type variable expression because there's no overload for `array(object:list[list[int]], dtype:np.float64])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `unknown` refer to the shape and data type of the array created.

Since `np.array` is just `np.ndarray(shape=(1,))` they have the same return type: `ndarray[_ShapeType@ndarray, _DType_co@ndarray]`

Therefore your code should work like this:

```
import numpy as np

a: np.ndarray[int, np.dtype[np.float64]] = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float64)
```

where `int` refers to the size tuple datatypes and `np.dtype[np.float64]` the array data's type

Comment: What is the logic of having to specify the type of the size tuple? Isn't it 'int' for all numpy arrays?

Comment: @CarlosPinzón see PEP 646, but TLDR it's because sometimes functions will want to specify either a fixed size for an axis, or a number of axes, or that axes should be in a particular order (e.g. Height x Width).  The best thing to do right now is `tuple[int, ...]` for a an array of any dimensions and size with no additional meaning attached to the arrays.